# What to do if malware not gone after complete factory reset?

Tags: security, networking, malware, antivirus, virus

I have a virus in my Samsung galaxy s21a, and even after a complete factory reset phone doesn't recover. What would be other solutions to fix it?

Comment: For Samsung there are PC based tools available which can download an original ROM: https://www.xda-developers.com/download-samsung-software-updates-samsung-firmware-downloader/ Such a downloaded ROM should be installable via Odin/Heimdall to reset the system partition.

Comment: What virus/malware survives a factory reset on a device without root access? (Legitimate question, not being snark)